# Dialog Transition Effects

Tags: android

I am currently working on the transition effects for my dialog. Please refer to the image below: [image]

The entrance animation for my dialog should be top to middle. While the exit animation should be middle to top. I am using the following XML animations, but unfortunately, they're not working.

slide_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" 
android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="50%p"
android:duration="1000"/>
```

EDIT: This is not a usual `Dialog`. It is an `activity` applied with a `Theme.Dialog` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: How are you applying these animations?

Comment: I think if you open `Dialogue Activity` then this transition is simple to implement.

Comment: what are you using? DialogFragment? paste the code where you apply transitions and commit transaction please.

Comment: I am using this method when I start/close an activity: `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_up);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are creating the dialog as an activity then you can follow this approach

You can create the animation classes :

```
public class DropDownToMiddleAnimation extends Animation {
    public int height, width;

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
            int parentHeight) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        setDuration(500);
        setFillAfter(true);
        setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    }

    Camera camera = new Camera();

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

        Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
        camera.save();

        camera.getMatrix(matrix);
        matrix.setTranslate(0, ((height/2) * interpolatedTime)) );

        matrix.preTranslate(0, -height);
        camera.restore();

        this.setAnimationListener(this);
    }
```

and :

```
public class MiddleToTopAnimation extends Animation {
    public int height, width;

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
            int parentHeight) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        setDuration(500);
        setFillAfter(true);
        setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    }

    Camera camera = new Camera();

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

        Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
        camera.save();

        camera.getMatrix(matrix);
        matrix.setTranslate(0, -((height/2) * interpolatedTime)) );//here is the change

        matrix.preTranslate(0, -height);
        camera.restore();

        this.setAnimationListener(this);
    }
```

and use them with your Dialog

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);//parent layout in the xml, which serves as the background in the custom dialog

ll.startAnimation(new DropDownToMiddleAnimation());//use with launching of the dialog

ll.startAnimation(new MiddleToTopAnimation());//use while dismissing the dialog/finishing the dialog activity
```

Comment: well, that's your design call. I use hard-coded animation classes as they can be re-used elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have to use hard-coded animations instead of XML. :)

Comment: can you also help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444018/frame-by-frame-animation-optimization

Comment: how can i hook up the LinearLAyout to the Dialog. I don't get that :/

Answer (score 2):

slide_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="-50%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
```